# Perform a calculation in a scene for Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I am new to coding for the Google Assistant. I wanted to make a simple calculator for my father. The flow would be:

1. Ask "How many acres did you cover"
2. How "many litres did you use"
3. Divide litres by acres
4. speak that resulting answer

I have already coded it to this point, but I do not know how I tell Google to perform the calculation. In the below response scene, it says the result as a fraction instead of performing the division.

```
        I hear you covered $session.params.Acres, and used
        $session.params.Litres. This means you used $session.params.Litres
        / $session.params.Acres per Acre
```

What is the correct method to perform this division?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scene cannot perform divisions or execute calculations. The session.params values that you are using are just number values in a sentence. The reason why it is says the result as a fraction is because it is trying to make a sentence using the / symbol. For instance "This means you used 1/2 per Acre.

If you want to perform any calculations you will have to do this through a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks) using code in a language that you are familiar with. Only step 3 would need to call your webhook as that would be the step that performs the calculation with the incoming parameters. You could then use the same response, but replace the `$session.params.Litres / $session.params.Acres per Acre` with the result of the division.

Comment: Thanks Jordi. I got that working and published to my family as alpha testers. Do you have any suggestions on a good training resource for developing for the google assistant? I am good with node.js, it is the scenes, intents, and interactions with web hooks that I would like to become more familiar with. It took a fair bit of trial and error to get this one working.

Comment: The actions on google docs would be the best place to start https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview